# Trying to split the metadata from ShoutCast

Tags: java, android, shoutcast

I am just trying to split the metadata (artist - song) provided by ShoutCast on my Android App. The code I implemented for handling this had been working fine (about 5 months, then the admin updated the shoutcast platform) until now. I think the new Shoutcast version changed the metadata format and added some special characters to it (mores whitespaces, maybe).

This is my current code, which was working perfect:

```
String meta_an = "";

artist_name.setText(meta_an.split("-")[0]);
song_name.setText(meta_an.split("-")[1]); //here is the error, index 1
```

Actually, the separator between both strings is " - ", but those lines was doing the job.

This is a metadata example: "Dorian Gray - Sjaj U Tami"

You can check it out here:
http://shoutcast.pondi.hr:8000/currentsong?sid=1

I suppose that there are no whitespaces at the beginning of the metadata, just in the middle.

On the other hand, I am catching this error:

[image]

Comment: May be there are some metadata that contains no "-"  character

Comment: Yes, it contains "-", It works for the first string [0], but [1]

Comment: If there is no "-" character the split method return array with one element, so you will only get artist name

Comment: I already tested printing out the full string before splitting, and yes buddy, there is a "-" character

Comment: Just try with String meta_an = "Hello";

Comment: I tried "Dragojevic Oliver & Gibonni - Srec", and it works fine, which means that the metadata contains some white spaces at the beginning or end maybe, but I dont know why split just makes one string, it should be 2 strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that Shoutcast was returning just one string in the metadata when starting to play the stream, the name of the Radio, (radio), so this first metadata didn't contain the " - " character, and the split function was just making one string. I added a conditional for checking if the metadata contains the " - " character, if so, it means that the split function can make 2 strings and I can get the values from the 0(artist) and 1(song) indexes.